# Database entries getting deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the script below, to clean sessions by a cronjob.

I want to clean up sessions that have been inactive for more than 40 minutes. 
But if they have a specific user_id they should last 1 day.

This doesn't work, and I can't see why. Sometimes they're getting removed even if they have the user_id.

```
DELETE FROM session
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN
            user_id IN (3,4,5,6,7)
        THEN
            expiry < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ELSE
            expiry < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 MINUTE)
    END
```

The data type of `user_id` is `int`, the data type of `expiry` is `datetime`.

Comment: Move the comparison outside the case and make it only return the value to compare to

Comment: Have you tried running a SELECT instead of a DELETE, to try to take a look at what's to be deleted? Try replacing `DELETE FROM session` with `SELECT user_id, expiry FROM session`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the comparison outside and not do it inside the case:

```
DELETE FROM session
  WHERE expiry < CASE
    WHEN user_id IN (3,4,5,6,7) THEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ELSE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 MINUTE)
  END
```

Comment: Can you tell the difference, or do you just know this is the solution ? :)

Comment: While I agree that this makes the comparison clearer, this shouldn't be necessary. The CASE-statement as written by the OP returns either true or false and the WHERE-clause should act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `CASE`?
Wouldn't it be simpler just like this:

`DELETE FROM session 
    WHERE expiry < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        OR 
    (expiry < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 MINUTE) AND user_id NOT IN (3,4,5,6,7))`

This way it would delete all expired by 1 day plus those expired by 40 minutes that have none of those ids.